# Faster alternative to extend-protocol jdbc/ISQLParameter for JDBC with Clojure

Tags: java, jdbc, clojure

```
(extend-protocol jdbc/ISQLParameter
  java.lang.String
  (set-parameter [v ^java.sql.PreparedStatement stmt ^long i]
    (let [param-meta (time (.getParameterMetaData stmt))
          param-type-name (time (.getParameterTypeName param-meta i))]
      (.setObject stmt i (case param-type-name
                           "uuid" (java.util.UUID/fromString v)
                           "timestamp" (parse-timestamp v)
                           v)))))
```

I'm doing this to automatically handle UUIDs. The only problem is that it's slow to the point of being unusable. `.getParameterMetaData` usually takes 100 ms to 300 ms, and this is done once for every argument when doing `where x in (?, ?, ?, ...)`! It's easy to realize that this makes certain queries impossible to run. Is there another option?